# Choosing one of two possible associations in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Newbie to rails here. I'm making an app to manage users, snippets of text, comments on the snippets, and likes.

Each user has many snippets and has many comments.
Each snippet belongs to some user, has many comments, and can have many likes. 
Each comment belongs to some user, belongs to a snippet, and can have many likes.

My issue is with the Like model. A like will belong to some user, and belong to EITHER a snippet or a comment.

My migration looks like this:

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :snippet # or :comment...?

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My Snippet model:

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :snippet
  has_many :likes
end
```

My Like model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :user
  # belongs to either :snippet or :comment, depending on
  # where the like is, and what controller it was submitted to
end
```

I can't reference both, and I feel like creating a new type of Like for every kind of content in the app would be messy.

How do I decide whether to pick between referencing a snippet or referencing a comment for each like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and easily accomplished with Rails and active record.

You'll need to modify your Like migration slightly to include an additional `_type` column. The easiest way to do this is in the migration.

```
def change
  create_table :likes do |t|
    # other columns ...
    t.references :likeable, polymorphic: true
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

All this does is create a `likeable_id` and a `likeable_type` column which will reference a particular `id` and class `type` (in your case, the `type` will be either "Comment" or "Snippet"). After this you can setup your associations like this

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end

class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at Polymorphic Associations in Rails. RailsCasts hava a good episode on this i.e http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association.

Here, I would create a polymorphic model for **Like** and make **Comments** and **Snippets** *likeable*.

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.integer :likeable_id
      t.string :likeable_type
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  belongs_to :user
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :snippet
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :user
  belongs_to :likeable, :polymorphic => true
  # belongs to either :snippet or :comment, depending on
  # where the like is, and what controller it was submitted to
end
```